# Is there an approach to predict the accuracy of a model without the test_labels?

Tags: scikit-learn, accuracy

I am working with the Loan Prediction Problem. My testset however does not contain the test labels. Is there any way in which accuracy score could be obtained without the test labels?

Comment: by holding out a validation set

Comment: that would be equivalent to slicing the training set and using half of it for validation. Okay, thanks!

Comment: @ArunaMaurya Note that there is no need to use half. It is problem dependent (and sample size dependent), although a good start might be 80/20: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610074/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-how-to-divide-a-dataset-into-training-and-validatio

Answer (score 1):

If your test set does not contain labels and your train set does, then you cannot compare the predicted labels against the actual labels during testing. *(So it is not really a 'test' set.)*

You should consider a different split for the data, such that there are labels for the test set. You may even consider using the unlabeled observations only in the train set in some form of [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning).

As I mentioned in the comments, you need not necessarily split your data in half. Other splits are also possible and depend on the sample size and the importance of validation vs. sufficient training data. If you are unsure, [a good start might be 80/20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610074/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-how-to-divide-a-dataset-into-training-and-validatio) (train/test).